# Changing the text of a uilabel then add new uilabel

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I want to change the text of a label, then have the user move it to where they want it on the screen (which is currently working) (the user hits - "Add text").

Once they place it where they would like.  I want the "Add text" button to create a new label that the user can move.  I'm not sure how to create these on the fly an to make sure that the gesture recognizers function with the new label.  Thanks for suggestions.

This is what I have now,,, doesn't work quite yet.

---

```
-(IBAction)addText:(id)sender
{
    textView.hidden=YES;


    labelShirt.text= textField.text;
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    [self addTextButtonPressed];

}



-(void)addTextButtonPressed
{
// CGRect *textFrame =
    // myInitialFrame is a CGRect you choose to place your label
    UILabel *myNewLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,100,100)];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                           action:@selector(labelMoved:)];
   myNewLabel.text =textField.text;

[self.view addSubview:myNewLabel];
}

-(void)labelMoved:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
    sender.view.frame = CGRectOffset(sender.view.frame, translation.x, translation.y);
}
```

Comment: Add the code you're using to add and move your first label, please!

Comment: I added the first label in interface builder.  The second time the label could even be rasterized and unmovable if thats easier.

Comment: and the gesture recognizer ? also in interface builder?

Comment: Yes, that is also in interface builder.  I guess I should do them programmatically, huh?

Comment: For the "newer" labels it has to be done programmatically. I'm gonna try to write a possible solution.

Comment: @David, unfortunately you can't really "clone" an existing IB object to make more of them.  As you're starting to realize, you'll need to create your label programmatically, add gesture recognizer(s) to it, etc.  Don't worry, it's not all that.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// The action that is added to your add text button
-(void)addTextButtonPressed
{
    // myInitialFrame is a CGRect you choose to place your label
    UILabel *myNewLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myInitialFrame];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                           action:@selector(labelMoved:)];
    myNewLabel.text = @"My initial text";
    // EDIT
    [self.view addSubview:myNewLabel];
    [myNewLabel addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
}

-(void)labelMoved:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
    sender.view.frame = CGRectOffset(sender.view.frame, translation.x, translation.y);
}
```

I don't know if that's enough to solve your problem, just comment if you still need more explanation.

Comment: Ok... I"m reading up on this now.  I think I need to add some things to get the gesture to work.

Comment: Tried this... I think I need to add the gesture recognizer, correct?     UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                           action:@selector(labelMoved:)];
    
    
    panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [view addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];

Comment: Sorry! It was too late at night and I was very tired. I'm gonna add the missing calls

Comment: Thanks for the help... works great, fixed the labelMoved as it flies off the screen but otherwise perfect.

Comment: How do I reference them after they are created?  Lets say I want to change the font size of the first one after three are added?

Comment: You can have a mutable array as a property and add them to it.